# How can I retrieve an element value from array in gfsh

Tags: gfsh

I have the following data in gfsh DB:

```
gfsh>query --query="select * from /siteinfo"

Result : true

Limit  : 100

Rows   : 4

Result

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id":"9347292b-cad8-4837-92b0-df34b8083901","lastUpdateTime":"1646376430201","fqdn":"test03.east.net","weight":1,"administrativeState":"unlocked","distributedSystemId":"3","lastSeenPeerUpdateTime":["4:1646376427321","1:1646376427321","2:1646376427321","3:1646376427321"],"siteLeader":false}
{"id":"1493a604-1ea2-44fa-9fe4-3cb99ed8d71b","lastUpdateTime":"1646376431751","fqdn":"test01.east.net","weight":1,"administrativeState":"unlocked","distributedSystemId":"1","lastSeenPeerUpdateTime":["2:1646376431235","4:1646376431235","3:1646376431235","1:1646376431235"],"siteLeader":true}
{"id":"73ddaee1-e586-42ce-8a78-c5c3ad324bba","lastUpdateTime":"1646376430995","fqdn":"test02.east.net","weight":1,"administrativeState":"unlocked","distributedSystemId":"2","lastSeenPeerUpdateTime":["2:1646376429276","4:1646376429276","1:1646376429276","3:1646376429276"],"siteLeader":false}
{"id":"150f58b5-e43e-40ef-a25d-2c5f2a69c06b","lastUpdateTime":"1646376430783","fqdn":"test04.east.net","weight":1,"administrativeState":"unlocked","distributedSystemId":"4","lastSeenPeerUpdateTime":["1:test","2:test","3:test","4:test"],"siteLeader":false}
```

You may see that there is no specific title in the result.(the 'Result' word is returned by gfsh)

```
gfsh>query --query="select e.value.Result from /siteinfo.entries e"

Result : true

Limit  : 100

Rows   : 4

Value

---------
UNDEFINED

UNDEFINED

UNDEFINED

UNDEFINED
```

How can I retrive the **'fqdn' only** for 'siteLeader' is 'true'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is here, because this is directly in the [Querying FAQ and Examples: Can I see query string examples, listed by query type?](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/getting_started/querying_quick_reference.html#reference_D5CE64F5FD6F4A808AEFB748C867189E__section_641D97CD874D4182961C85429ACA1B05) page and not all that much different from regular SQL:

```
select s.fqdn from /siteinfo s where s.siteLeader = true
```

Comment: the query above doesn't work.

Comment: @walkaround2002 you have to be a lot more specific than that. "does not work" is the worst error description. What is the error message? Is there an error or is only the result wrong/unexpected? …

Comment: Hi @knittl,

gfsh>query --query="select s.fqdn from /siteinfo s where s.siteLeader = true"
Result : true
Limit  : 100
Rows   : 0